# Unexpected token } onclick event

Tags: syntax, checkbox, click, token

I browsed though many "unexpected token", "illegal" etc. topics, one helped me by checking for invisible characters and copying the script to jslint throwed me some missed brackets error, but there are still one problem with this line:

JS:

```js
document.getElementById('pois').innerHTML =('<p><label><input type="checkbox" id="01" onclick="toggleGroup("01")" CHECKED/></label>01</p>');
```

The pois div is located in the html file.

Alternatively, how would I write the above line with jQuery, as the inline JS is not considered correct? The below function doesn't work as I'd like:

```js
$("#01").click(function() {
    toggleGroup();
});
```

The corresponding function:

```js
var markerGroups = { "01": [], "02": [] , "03": [] , "04": [] };
function toggleGroup(id_category) {
    for (var i = 0; i < markerGroups[id_category].length; i++) {
    var marker = markerGroups[id_category][i];
    if (marker.getMap()) {
        marker.setMap(null);
    } else {
        marker.setMap(map);
       }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to change `onclick` to `onchange`? This will capture the tick box change event. I'm not too sure what the toggleGroup function is doing but this might help.

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't help. There are four checkboxes with map markers, the togglegroup function should show/hide markers in their groups.

Answer (score 0):

The error raised because you have missed one bracket `}` on end of your function

```
function toggleGroup(id_category) {
    for (var i = 0; i < markerGroups[id_category].length; i++) {
    var marker = markerGroups[id_category][i];
    if (marker.getMap()) {
        marker.setMap(null);
    } else {
        marker.setMap(map);
   }
    }
} //<== missing one
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QF9sN/5/

Comment: Thank you, but that's what I have in my JS file, I just forgot to type the closing bracket here, sorry for the confusion. I forgot to mention that everything is in a JS file and perhaps the error caused by that, I've updated my question according to that.

Comment: since you appended new HTML, you have to rebind the event click or use .on('click') instead. 
$("#01").on('click', function() {
    toggleGroup("1");
});

Comment: Thanks. It works! Only with: toggleGroup("01") - note the zero. How can I accept your comment as the answer?

Comment: yeah, it does http://jsfiddle.net/QF9sN/11/.
You just mark this answer as accept, it is enough